# Q: AWS DynamoDB to S3 [pipeline]

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, backup

The goal that I wish to achieve is to generate a file of the table, so that afterwards that can be checked for data (monthly calculations). What I have done so far is to create a Backup using the PipeLine option from DynamoDB to an S3 bucket, but:

- It is taking too long, the pipeline has been running for more than 24h since the table I am exporting is 7 GB in DynamoDB size (which is compressed and it will take even more time to finish with the backup);
- I will need to do that monthly, which means that I will only need the data between first and last day of the month, while the PIPELINE can create a backup I could not find an option to make it so that only the changes in the table from specific timelines is exported;
- The files that the Pipeline export are around 10 MB each and that means hundreds of files, instead of a couple (for example 100 MB files or 1 GB files).

In this case I am interested if there is a different way which I can make a full backup of current information and afterwards do a month to month on the changes that where performed (something like a monthly incremental) and not to have millions of 10 MB files.

Any comments, clarifications, code samples, corrections are appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: From what I read around, I think there is no golden solution to this. You can try to hack up some own backing up tools, or look for some third party ones.

Answer (score 0):

You have, basically, two options:

1. Implement your own logic by DynamoDB Steams and process your data by
   your own logic
2. Use combination on AWS Glue for ETL processing and,
   possible, AWS Athena for query your data from S3. Be careful and use
   Apache Parquet format for better query performance and cache your
   results somewhere else

Comment: In this case could you share more light on the DynamoDB Streams that you have mentioned, since it needs to be something simple and from what I can see it will pass the update of data at the moment of it happens to lambda, which means that there will be a thousand of files. The goal would be to simply make it so that when information in table "LetsDance" (for example) when an update happens between 1-30 of month it will not export it to S3 until the last day of the month in it's respective folder [ automatically create a folder of database name/month ]?